# How to have nested object inside namespace variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, javascript-namespaces

I am programming using namespaces, and so far I have only used variables and functions inside it. I tried to do a nested object in it, but it doesn't seem to work like I expect it. Here's the code

```
const myNameSpace = {

    someVar: '',
    otherVar: '',

    someFunc() {
        // code here
    },

    nestedObject: {
        param1: '',
        param2: '',
        param3: ''
    }
};
```

other variables work fine, but when I try to access `param1`, like this

```
myNameSpace.nestedObject.param1
```

it returns undefined, rather than an empty string like I have declared it. Also accessing only `myNameSpace.nestedObject` returns an empty string...

What is wrong with this, and is it even possible what I want?

Comment: it is working fine, are you sure, you use an ES6 system?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, I am using all other ES6 things with no problem

Comment: is it the whole object which does not work? have you tried to use a smaller object and test it?

Comment: @NinaScholz the problem was that I was resetting the nestedObject whole value to an empty string before accessing it, thats why it didn't work. But I still had to ask if it's the right way to do, because I never declared nested objects inside namespace variables before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected, 
Run following code snippet.

```js
const myNameSpace = {

    someVar: '',
    otherVar: '',

    someFunc() {
        // code here
    },

    nestedObject: {
        param1: 'param 1 value',
        param2: 'param 2 value',
        param3: 'param 3 value'
    }
};

console.log(myNameSpace.nestedObject.param1);
```

Comment: how does this help? op had posted a valid code with no errors.